# this.myservice.getData is not a function error give in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to fetch data from a API. I followed this tutorial in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular7/angular7_http_client.htm tutorials point> I have done the project as guided by this tutorial. But this error is given in console

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: this.myservice.getData is not a function
    at AppComponent.ngOnInit (app.component.ts:62)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31909)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44366)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44305)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45327)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45270)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45258)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44270)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45631)
```

[image]

These are my source code

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { GoogleChartsModule } from 'angular-google-charts';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {ApiService} from './api.service';

import {MyserviceServiceService} from './myservice-service.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    GoogleChartsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [ApiService,MyserviceServiceService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

myservice-service.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyserviceServiceService {

  private finaldata = [];
  private apiurl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getData() {
     return this.http.get(this.apiurl);
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import {MyserviceServiceService} from './myservice-service.service';

import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular 7 Project!';
  public persondata = [];
  constructor(private myservice: MyserviceServiceService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
     this.myservice.getData().subscribe((data) => {
        this.persondata = Array.from(Object.keys(data), k=>data[k]);
        console.log(this.persondata);
     });
  }
}
```

anyone can give me the solution for the problem?

Comment: restart your server and run again

Comment: `MyserviceServiceService`? May proper naming conventions RIP. 

Comment: `app.component.ts` and `App.component.ts` duplicated code? edit your post..

Answer (score 0):

Use https instead of http in MyServiceServiceService.ts

```
private apiurl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
```

[stackblitz-answer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-questions-58425257?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: if it was https issue then it wont throw exception as shown above. https issue will be have different message `The page at 'https://stackblitz.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the question was asked but I see an issue with HTML code on the provided link.

[image: The list tag should be ending with > and not with <]

I think the service might have been created outside the app folder and that could be the reason why function is not accessible. If you have the same folder structure as I have, it should work as expected (of course after fixing the list tag).

[image: Folder structure]

Output:

[image: Output]